# Python.Как в PyCharm поставить настройку подсветки аннотации типов?

Tags: python, pycharm

Как-то наткнулся на видео в ютубе, где показывалось, какие галочки нужно в настройках убрать, чтобы не загружался pycharm столь долго. Потом Сбросил настройки ,чтобы вернуть по умолчанию, но видимо какие-то галочки остались. В общем мне надо подсветка чтобы была когда в аннотации типов указан один тип, а я пишу другой. Ниже пример, по логике должно подсвечивать "ss" предупреждением, но pycharm не замечает это.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на всякий случай код ниже

```
def mul2(x:int):
return x * 5

res = mul2("ss")
print(res)
```

Comment: Проверьте, что не включено File - Power Save Mode

Answer (score 0):

Подсветка неверного типа находится в `Settings > Editor > Inspections`.
Нужный вам параметр в группе `Python > Incorrect type`
[image: Inspections tab]

Comment: спасибо, галочка стоит на этом параметре, но почему то не подсвечивает

Comment: @sagittarius а в полях Scope, Severity, Highlighting in editor тоже самое стоит?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду Settings > Editor > ? Я там таких полей не нашёл . Также и в Settings > Editor > Inspections их не вижу

Comment: @sagittarius это выпадающие списки справа, при выборе Incorrect type, как на скриншоте

Comment: ааа , извините. У меня почему то только выпадающий список  Severity . Точнее вот так  https://prnt.sc/nh-eqp61XVBF

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема была в режиме чтения pycharm. Стоял режим чтения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того как его закрыл(крестик слева при наведении)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

начало всё как надо ругаться.